# table created in SQL management studio will not show up in Visual studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

table created in SQL management studio will not show up in Visual studio
When I try to create Light Switch App. I just added new table as an appendix to existing database with existing tables. All native tables will show up, except the new one. Any idea?
Table Exist in Server Explorer but not in solution explorer

Comment: seems like some access issue

Comment: `You can add tables to the LightSwitch internal database. Conversely, you cannot add tables or other abstractions to external data sources such as a SQL Server database, SharePoint list, or WCF RIA Service by using LightSwitch. For those data sources, LightSwitch generates entities that match the structure of the data source.` - source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851993.aspx

Comment: Did you update the datasource in your solution? (Right Click on your Datasource in Solution Explorer under Server/Data Sources --> Click Update Datasource). A dialog will appear where you can check which tables you want to update/add to your solution-datasource

Comment: this has happened to me before with views because of an issue with the constraints.... so for example the table may not have a primary key referenced in your case, in my case its because the view didnt have a key field and had nothing to compare against. If this is not the case then post the code that created your table...